# preserve dataframe columns order while is it appended

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
source  target  w1  w2 
1       2       1   0
1       3       1   0     
1       4       1   0
```

and I'm trying to achieve this:

```
source  target  w1
1       2       1 
1       3       1      
1       4       1
2       1       0
3       1       0
4       1       0
```

I simply need to append the current dataframe to itself, but with the first two columns (**source** and **target**) reversed, and to rename **w2** to **w1**.

When I use the append or concat function I always get results looking like:

```
source  target  w1
1       2       1 
1       3       1      
1       4       1
1       2       0
1       3       0
1       4       0
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what you've tried

Comment: Why does the `3` in the 3rd row, target column of the dataframe turn to a `4` in the dataframe you are trying to achieve?  Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: @Bill I guess that in raw table target column is 2,3,4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we can create our "to append" dataframe with [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor, and use [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) append them together:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'source':df['target'],
                    'target':df['source'],
                    'w1':df['w2']})

df = df.drop(columns='w2').append(df2)
```

Or you can use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to get rid of the index labels, and just the `array` behind your `df`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[['target', 'source', 'w2']].to_numpy(), 
                   columns=['source', 'target', 'w1'])

df = df.drop(columns='w2').append(df2)
```

**Output**

```
   source  target  w1
0       1       2   1
1       1       3   1
2       1       4   1
0       2       1   0
1       3       1   0
2       4       1   0
```

**Bonus**

Instead of `DataFrame.drop` + `DataFrame.append`, you can use:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2], join='inner')
```

The `join='inner'` argument will only keep the overlapping columns.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `pd.concat` with rename columns.

```
cols_1 = ['source', 'target', 'w1']
cols_2 = ['target', 'w1', 'w2']

df_concat = pd.concat([df[cols_1], 
                       df[cols_2].rename(columns=dict(zip(cols_2, cols_1)))], 
                                         ignore_index=True)

Out[701]:
   source  target  w1
0       1       2   1
1       1       3   1
2       1       4   1
3       2       1   0
4       3       1   0
5       4       1   0
```